# lookup column to load list(created to use in the lookup column) from current site not from the parent site where the lookup column is created

Tags: lookup-column

I have created a Lookup Column called "LookupSiteColumnA" in the parent site , I have created a List "ParentSiteSourceList" in the parent Site to use for Lookup Column , and saved this list as a Template so that I want to define the list in child site to load the data to Child Site List look up column , but the Child Site lookup column is loading the data from the "ParentSiteSourceList" in the parent site. but I want to load the lookup values from the list which in child site.

Comment: Do you need to change this just for one child site? Or do you want to modify list template?

Comment: I need to create List with lookup column  in each sub site , and I will create List from ParentSiteSourceList (data for Lookup column ) template . in  a sub site the List lookup column must point to the list in the current site.  I can not use visual studio.

Comment: You need to modify list template. I will add little guide later.

Comment: Ok, I am currently modifying list template to replace guid with List name , I will update you the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get list template from Site Actions > List Templates page.
2. Save it to your PC (as `.stp` file)
3. Open it as archive (with WinRAR, e.g.)
4. extract `manifest.xml`
5. Find the column's definition
6. Change `List` attribute from `guid` to relative path: `List="{0273b5af-ff4e-49c4-ac09-49394ac936e1}"` to `List="Lists\CustomList"`
7. compress `manifest.xml` as `.cab` file by following command in command promt:

   `makecab "C:\List Templates\ListBTemplate\manifest.xml" "C:\List Templates\ListBTemplate\ListBTemplate.cab"`
8. Change `.cab` extension to `.stp`
9. Load newer `.stp` file to list templates library